# Unable to align image in middle vertically inside a DIV

Tags: css, image

I have been trying to align image inside a div vertically but it seems impossible to me

I have tried to give anchor `a` of `img` these styles

```
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 190px;
```

Here is the link to my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmuLz6hz/)

I have acheived these things that image height should never get more than the DIV and its width should never be less than the width of DIV

Can someone correct me how do I get this image in middle vertically?

Update:

Here it is on my live site

http://www.wholesalerhinestones.org/testtest.html

Comment: Heres a great example of what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/4570/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to the `image`, here's the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmuLz6hz/1/)

### Edit

for your live site, change the style of `.link_image` to

```
.link_image {
    width: 212px;
    height: 190px;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and for `.transfers_image`, remove the `display: inline-block;`. It's not needed

Comment: Here it is on my live site ... anything I try it does not work there